# Linking libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

I am getting link error 'undefined external symbols' in my visual studio 2013 c++ program. But when I add the required library, another error shows up which says 'The functionality is already implemented in mvscr120.dll'. I don't quiet understand how to fix this. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set /MT flag.

Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - C/C++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library

Look into the first option (/MD)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx